# How can I upgrade from Windows 8 to 10 for free?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, upgrade

I have an old Windows 8 machine which I want to upgrade to Win 10 for free. My copy of Windows 8 is legal and activated of course, and I have the activation key.

I know that the free upgrade officially ended a year ago, but I've read that there are still ways of upgrading for free.

Is this true? Is it still possible to receive a free upgrade to Windows 10?

Comment: [Here's how you can still get a free Windows 10 upgrade](http://www.zdnet.com/article/heres-how-you-can-still-get-a-free-windows-10-upgrade/)

Comment: Try this [Windows 10 Assistive technology Upgrade](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/accessibility/windows10upgrade)

Comment: @DavidPostill I read this article before posting. This is why I've mentioned that I read it is somehow possible. However, for some reason, I didn't get the  impression that it will 100% work in any case. The article says that it worked for the author (in more than one machine), but he doesn't really know why, or how it happened. So I wounder, what will happen if after installation, I will not be able to activate Windows. would it still work? In previous win versions, I know that after some time lot of functionalities were simply disabled.

Comment: @OJNSim I've never done it so I don't know.

Answer (score 5):

As of early 2017, the Disability Upgrade / Accessibility Upgrade was still available to people with sight  disabilities.  It still requires that you have a valid Win7 , Win8, or Win8.1 license to start the process.

[Here is How](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/accessibility/windows10upgrade)

Comment: Not sure I understand...How is this being enforced? or it actually will work for everyone?

Comment: It's intended for use by those with vision difficulties, but isn't enforced as far as I know.  In several cases, I have simply formatted PCs which used to have Win7 or Win8, put on Win10.  I put in their old Win7 or Win8 keys when asked to authenticate Win10, and it was accepted.  As of 6/22/2017 I don't know if that's still valid method.

Answer (score 0):

There is still a way you can upgrade for free!

Here are the steps:

1. Go to the website [Windows 10 Upgrade](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
2. Click Download Tool Now
3. Follow the steps in the installer software.

I have tried this installer on all of my devices and it works.